# What is the antecedent of "The x of y, which"

Tags: ambiguity, antecedents

What is the antecedent of "which" in the following sentence?

"The door of the car, which is discontinued, broke."

Is the "the door of the car" discontinued, or is "the car" discontinued?

Comment: It's ambiguous. It could be either. It would need to be rephrased if an explicit antecedent is required.